# Highlight [Add Class] the biggest value of each table column

Tags: jquery

I'll give you the link to exact table i wanna do this: http://pt.omerta-stats.tk/?page=smuggling

For example, the first table on that page. The table has 8 cities on the left and the price of 7 products in each city. Let's focus on `Morphine` column. In one of those cities the price will be the highest and on other city there will be lowest. I want to add a css class to those table cells.

This would have to be done to all table columns.

Feel free to use PHP, JQuery, simple JavaScript, pure CSS, or others.

Comment: I'm gonna be out of the pc for the next hour and a half, so if you have questions, i'll just answer than, sorry

Comment: Cool, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following will do the trick for you.  You can refactor this to be more generic as I'm just dealing with your specific example to get you started.

```
var tdCount = $('#narcsTable tr:eq(1) td').length,
    trCount = $('#narcsTable tr').length;

for (var i = 1; i < tdCount; i++) {
    var $td = $('#narcsTable tr:eq(2) td:eq(' + i + ')'),
        highest = 0,
        lowest = 9e99;

    for (var j = 3; j < trCount; j++) {
        $td = $td.add('#narcsTable tr:eq(' + j + ') td:eq(' + i + ')');
    }

    $td.each(function(i, el){
        var $el = $(el);
        if (i >= 0) {
            var val = parseInt($el.text().replace(/[\$,]/g, ''), 10);
            if (val > highest) {
                highest = val;
                $td.removeClass('high');
                $el.addClass('high');
            }
            if (val < lowest) {
                lowest = val;
                $td.removeClass('low');
                $el.addClass('low');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Edited to `i >= 0` because the first i is 0 (Demo wasn't updated)

### [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ttqb8/)

Comment: Actually it is not working on the first row :/ check this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ttqb8/3/ ; Morphine and Marijuana prices in Detroit should highlight. I tried to work with the code but couldnt solve this. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes cell value is empty in this case none of the above answer will work i have a solution for this by updating @mVChr code.

```
function HighlightColumn() {
        try {
            var tdCount = $('#narcsTabletr:eq(1) td').length;
            var trCount = $('#narcsTabletr').length;

            for (var i = 1; i < tdCount; i++) {
                var $td = $('#narcsTabletr:eq(2) td:eq(' + i + ')');

                for (var j = 3; j < trCount; j++) {
                    $td = $td.add('#narcsTabletr:eq(' + j + ') td:eq(' + i + ')');
                }
                var cellprice = [];
                $td.each(function (i, el) {
                    var $el = $(el);
                    var cellValue = parseInt($el.text().replace(/[\$,]/g, ''), 10);
                    if (!isNaN(cellValue)) {
                        cellprice.push(cellValue);
                    }
                });

               // console.log(cellprice);

                var minValue = cellprice.min();
                var maxValue = cellprice.max();

              //  console.log('minValue=' + minValue);
              //  console.log('maxValue=' + maxValue);

                $td.each(function (i, el) {
                    var $el = $(el);
                    if (i >= 0) {
                        var cellValue = parseInt($el.text().replace(/[\$,]/g, ''), 10);

                        if (cellValue == minValue) {
                            $el.addClass('low');
                        }
                        if (cellValue == maxValue) {
                            $el.addClass('high');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (exception) {
            console.log(exception);
        }
    }
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "max", {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: false,
        writable: false,
        value: function () {
            return Math.max.apply(null, this);
        }
    });
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "min", {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: false,
        writable: false,
        value: function () {
            return Math.min.apply(null, this);
        }
    });
```